# Extra numbers printed after printf

Tags: c, time.h

This is my program for calculating the age.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {

    int d1, d2, m1, m2, y1, y2, d3, m3, y3;

    struct tm *t;
    time_t ts;

    ts = time(NULL);
    t = localtime(&ts);

    printf ("\n Enter date of birth (dd-mm-yyyy) : ");
    scanf ("%2d-%2d-%4d",&d1,&m1,&y1);

    d2 = t->tm_mday;
    m2 = t->tm_mon + 1;
    y2 = t->tm_year + 1900;

    printf ("\n Current Date : %d-%d-%d\n",d2,m2,y2); //Problem on this line

    d3 = d2 - d1;
    m3 = m2 - m1;
    y3 = y2 - y1;

    printf ("%d%d%d",d3,m3,y3);

    if (d3 < 0){
        d3 += 30;
        m3 -= 1;
    }
    if (m3 < 0){
        m3 = 12 + m3;
        y3 = y3 - 1;
    }


    printf ("\n You Are %d Year(s) %d Month(s) %d Day(s) Old",y3,m3,d3);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem's on the 14th line where the current date is printed. I entered 16-10-2000 as the input and every time I run the program, I get this number, "10-817" after the line-break on line 14. This number changes if I change the input. Why is this extra number printed after I run my program and how can I fix it?

Comment: SO isn't a debugging service. Compile with symbols, run the code inside a debugger to trace through the program(s) line by line inspecting the values of the relevant variables to learn what is *really* going on. If then a *specific* question arises feel free to come back here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`printf ("%d%d%d",d3,m3,y3);` This is your extra line. Remove it

If you want to know where the values came from then:

```
d3 = d2 - d1;// 26 - 16 = 10 
m3 = m2 - m1;// 2 - 10 = -8
y3 = y2 - y1;// 2017 - 2000 = 17
```

Hence 10-817

Comment: I figured it out. But I didn't notice the extra printf.

Answer (score 3):

There is no extra numbers printed after you execute the program. In your program you have 3 printf()

1. prompt to get date of birth
2. to print current date
3. difference between the date of birth and current date
4. End result

You are thinking you are getting extra numbers printed due to 3rd printf(). so comment it or remove it which is present at line number 27

Comment: also note that the calculation of the difference in the dates can/will have negative numbers.  Suggest displaying those values with a space between them.